# How do you set the 'tail probabilities' in a scipy genextreme distribution?

Tags: statistics, scipy

Does anyone know how to set the 'q' parameter(which controls the lower or upper tail probability) in scipy's 'genextreme' distribution?

> #/usr/bin/env python
>
> import numpy as np
> import pylab as plt
> from scipy.stats import genextreme
>
> mu, sigma = 10, 4
> # QUESTION: How do you set q, the lower or upper tail probability, in genextreme?
> rv = genextreme(c=[0], loc=mu, scale=sigma)
> x  = np.linspace(0, 40, 50) # Generate 50 values from 0-40
>
> y_pdf = rv.pdf(x)
> plt.plot( x, y_pdf, 'ro-', label='PDF' )
>
> y_cdf = rv.cdf(x)
> plt.plot( x, y_cdf, 'b*-', label='CDF' )
>
> plt.legend()
> plt.show()

@Warren:  Thanks for the information.  I am new to scipy stats.  How can I move the distribution so the pdf is more heavily weighted at the upper end?  I tried changing the 'c' param to [0.9], but the output was very choppy, with a hocky-stick rise and then a dramatic almost straight-line fall to zero where it stayed.

Answer (score 2):

`q` is not a parameter of scipy's [genextreme distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html).   It is the argument to the methods `ppf` (inverse of the cdf) and `isf` (inverse of the survival function). If you look at the documentation for other distributions--e.g. [norm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html), [gamma](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html)--you'll see that all the class-level docstrings list `q` in their "parameters", but that documentation is an overview of the arguments to all the methods. `genextreme` has the standard location and scale parameters, and one shape parameter, `c`.

Example:

```
>>> genextreme.cdf(genextreme.ppf(0.95, c=0.5), c=0.5)
0.94999999999999996
```

You can find more about the [generalized extreme distribution on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution), but note that the shape parameter used in scipy has the opposite sign as the shape parameter in the wikipedia article.  For example, the following generates the wikipedia plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import genextreme

# Create the wikipedia plot.
plt.figure(1)
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 201)
plt.plot(x, genextreme.pdf(x, 0.5), color='#00FF00', label='c = 0.5')
plt.plot(x, genextreme.pdf(x, 0.0), 'r', label='c = 0')
plt.plot(x, genextreme.pdf(x, -0.5), 'b', label='c = -0.5')
plt.ylim(-0.01, 0.51)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.title('Generalized extreme value densities')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: genextreme densities]

When `c` < 0, the left end of the support of the distribution is `loc + scale / c`.  The following creates a plot of the distribution with `c = -0.25`, `scale = 5`, and `loc = -scale / c` (so the left end of the support is at 0):

```
c = -0.25
scale = 5
loc = -scale / c
x = np.linspace(0, 80, 401)
pdf = genextreme.pdf(x, c, loc=loc, scale=scale)
plt.plot(x, pdf)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Density')
```

Plot:

[image: genextreme example]

The [`stats` tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats.html) on the scipy documentation site has more information about the distribution classes, including a section on [shifting and scaling a distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats.html#shifting-and-scaling).